# C# post-запрос с файлом и данными

Tags: c#, post

Можно ли POST-запросом отправить одновременно файл, допустим XXX.txt на сервер и значение для какого-то поля/переменной, допустим "Ju2qQw". То есть мне нужно передать на мой сервер файл и одновременно какую-то информацию относящуюся к данному файлу. Если это можно сделать, то прошу, укажите через что это можно сделать, если нельзя - то чем воспользоваться для решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
string uri = "http://server.com/file";
string localPath = "/tmp/XXX.txt";
var parameters = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
{
    { "yourVariableName", "Ju2qQw" }
};

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    client.QueryString = parameters;
    var responseBytes = client.UploadFile(uri, localPath);
    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
}
```

(Я не уверен, сработает ли это, мне не на чем попробовать.)

---

Для случая, когда сервер не понимает параметры в запросе, подойдёт код из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048296/276994). Скопирую его сюда для удобства. Автор кода пользователь en.SO [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov).

```
public class UploadFile
{
    public string Name;
    public string Filename;
    public string ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    public Stream Stream;
}

void SendAsciiString(string s, Stream stream)
{
    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

void SendString(string s, Stream stream)
{
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

public byte[] UploadFiles(
        string uri,
        IEnumerable<UploadFile> files,
        NameValueCollection variables)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(address);
    request.Method = "POST";
    var boundary = new string('-', 27) +
        DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    boundary = "--" + boundary;

    var boundaryBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + "\r\n");

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        // Write the values
        foreach (string name in values.Keys)
        {
            requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
            SendAsciiString(string.Format(
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n",
                    name),
                requestStream);
            SendString(values[name] + "\r\n", requestStream);
        }

        // Write the files
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
            SendString(string.Format(
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n",
                    file.Name, file.Filename),
                requestStream);
            SendAsciiString(string.Format(
                    "Content-Type: {0}\r\n\r\n", file.ContentType),
                requestStream);
            file.Stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            SendAsciiString("\r\n", requestStream);
        }

        SendAsciiString(boundary + "--\r\n", requestStream);
    }

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Похожий подход предлагается в [этой статье](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8600/UploadFileEx-C-s-WebClient-UploadFile-with-more-fu), ещё несколько ссылок аналогичного содержания [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2952279/276994).

Comment: Протестировал, работает: `?yourVariableName=Ju2qQw` в URL присутствует, заголовки и содержимое файла тоже на месте.

Comment: @Regent: Спасибо! Но всё же переспрошу. Приходит именно POST? Я сейчас читаю [вот этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2952279/276994), и в обсуждении говорится, что работать не должно, и нужна кастомная имплементация. Где подвох?

Comment: На здоровье. Да, уходит POST, проверял в Wireshark. Не вижу причин почему сервер может не смочь обработать параметр, указанный в URL. Я внимательно не вчитывался в кучу ссылок из указанного ответа, но у меня сложилось впечатление, что все проблемы там из-за желания затолкать данные-параметры и файл в тело запроса

Comment: @Regent: Возможно, код на той стороне ожидает `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="yourVariableName"\r\n\r\nJu2qQw`. Но это уж пускай уточняет ОП.

Comment: @VladD зависит от кода на той стороне. если там какой-нибудь asp.net mvc, то стандартный байндер нормально вытащит значение `yourVariableName` из GET-строки вместо тела запроса. Если там какой-нибудь php - то код будет ждать `yourVariableName` именно в теле запроса.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно! Однако, я не понял, а где указывается переменная в которую загружать собственно файл? Простите за мою неграмотность, я с вебом вообще до этого почти не работал.

Comment: @x0m: в `localPath` указываете путь к файлу

Comment: @VladD нет, вы не поняли, у меня в скрипте(тот что на сервере) примерно такой код 

`$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

насколько я понимаю, нужно же заливать файл в переменную file, разве не так? Если нет, то как? Еще раз извиняюсь за свою глупость

Comment: @x0m: Я, к сожалению, не очень знаком с PHP. и не смогу тут подсказать.

Comment: @VladD а вы когда тестировали, какой код использовали или вы не тестировали данный код? Если все таки тестировали, то пожалуйста, залейте куда-нибудь исходник с кодом на стороне сервера.

Comment: @x0m: Я не тестировал, у меня нет сервера, который бы принял данные.

Answer (score 4):

Господа, я нашел еще одно решение своей проблемы  - использование сторонней библиотеки xNet. Может быть кому это будет интересно, вот пример кода для решения моей задачи.

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest()) {
    var multipartContent = new MultipartContent() {
        {new StringContent("Bill Gates"), "login"},
        {new StringContent("qwerthahaha"), "password"},
        {new FileContent(@"C:\windows_9_alpha.rar"), "file1", "1.rar"}
    };

    request.Post("www.microsoft.com", multipartContent).None();
}
```

Пример взят отсюда: http://habrahabr.ru/post/146475/

Comment: Посмотрел на библиотеку xNet. У них там вовсе нет async-методов! Это значит, что каждый запрос будет блокировать по крайней мере один поток, что не очень-то комильфо. Тем не менее, +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
async Task UploadFile(string url, byte[] bytes, string name, string filename = null)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    using (var content = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        content.Add(new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)), name, filename ?? "q");

        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
}
```