# С# передача файла в теле POST запроса

Tags: c#, post, header

Возникла задача отправлять email напрямую из программы.
По мимо просто текста прикреплять файл лога к письму.
Решил использовать сторонний шлюз и через API выполнять указанную задачу.
С отправкой просто текста(небольших объёмов текста) проблем нет, а вот процедуру  вложения не могу осилить.
В доках к API написано:

> Если при отправке планируется передача каких-либо файлов, то их
>   необходимо передавать методом POST в теле http-запроса к серверу.

Итого пришел к такому:

```
WebRequest link = WebRequest.Create(server);
            link.Method = "POST";
            link.Headers.Add("login",cfg.sms_router_user);
            link.Headers.Add("psw", cfg.sms_router_pwd);
            link.Headers.Add("phones", cfg.sms_router_email);
            link.Headers.Add("mes", mes);
            link.Headers.Add("sender", CALBACK_EMAIL);
            link.Headers.Add("subj",subj);
            link.Headers.Add("mail","1");
            link.Timeout = 100000;
            link.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            FileStream file = new FileStream(path_file,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            byte[] rData = new byte[file.Length];
            file.Read(rData,0,rData.Length);
            link.ContentLength = rData.Length;
            Stream sendTR = link.GetRequestStream();
            sendTR.Write(rData,0,rData.Length);
            sendTR.Close();
```

По итогу получаю ошибку "неверные параметры". Может я не верно понял слова передавать в теле) наставьте на путь истинный .

Если не прикреплять файл, то отправка письма проходит GET запросом

```
send.php?login=<login>&psw=<password>&phones=<phones>&mes=<message>&sender=<sender>&subj=<subj>&mail=1
```

Я так понял что через метод POST тоже нужно указывать эти параметры и плюс файл вложения в теле POST запроса

Comment: Либо [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702319/Как-сделать-post-запрос-загрузки-аудио-файла-вконтакте-vk-api-c) ну или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431214/c-post-запрос-с-файлом-и-данными/431219#431219), что то из этого явно напрашивается как дубликат )

Comment: у вас нарушен страндарт `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @nick_n_a  а что должно быть?

Comment: Должно в запросе быть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829316/17974, а как это сделать - пройтись по ссылкам EvgeniyZ